# Azure Devops - Organisation deleted after some time

Tags: azure-devops

Don't know if I'm right here. But didn't know where to ask.

I created an azure devops - organisation. After that I created some projects.
After some time the organisation disappeared. This happend 3 times now and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Can anybody help?

[Update] I'm now in contact with MS. They couldn't help in first place because the hard delete date was gone. I created a new organisation and waiting until it is deleted. After that I will contact them again.

Comment: could you explain a bit on `organization disappeared`? what screen you are getting?

Comment: When opening visual studio and clicking on webportal to any project there, I'm getting an 404. After that I'm going to my profile site in azure devops and there is no organisation anymore. I can recreate it new with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be on Microsoft end.

Check:

> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/265570/getting-404-error-page-while-trying-to-enter-into-1.html

You can report to MS if this issue persists.

Comment: Tried to write an email to the mailadress in the post but it isn't accepted from the reciepient. But thanks for pointing to this post!